# Highlight quotes with blockquote in Low Quality Posts popup

Tags: feature-request, design, low-quality-posts, localization

Is it possible to eliminate double quote symbols around comment text in Low Quality Posts popup and use block quote highlighting like in regular post instead?

> [image: LQP]

I think using some kind of universal highlighting would be preferred while using in many languages UI. For instance, on SO in Russian using such quotes is not correct according typographical rules in Russian language:

> [image: LQP ru]

Alternative solution would be to allow translators change these quote symbols. Now they are hardcoded and can't be different site by site.

Comment: Indeed one might ask what the quotation marks are needed for at all.

Comment: @mdewey I think the quotation here is used because the quoted message will be posted as a comment for recommended to delete post.

Comment: I mean, close reasons eventually get posted under the question too, just in a banner. But we don't use quotes there. I'd say this is just an ugly inconsistency. We should just remove them. :/